# Why sending simulated keypress to terminal does not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, terminal, hotkeys

### Problem

This code allows me to simulate key commands in my termial
`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down'`
But the only key codes that work are (`124` or `123`)

### What Works

Next Desktop Space
`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down'`

Previous Desktop Space
`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 123 using control down'`

### What Doesn't Work

Mission Control 
`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 40 using control down'`

Or anything other than (`124` or `123`).

### What Am I Looking For

An **explanation** for why I can only use `124` and `123` to simulate key presses in terminal for `controlling my System`.

I want to control `mission control` as well as other hotkeys associated with my system.

### Questions

**OS?**
`Mac`

**Does your hotkey combination match what you are trying to simulate in the terminal?**
`Yes`

**Why are you trying to do this?**
`To create an app that can navigate my system on it's own`

**Do you really need this simulate key commands in the terminal?**
`Yes`

**Why not just use multiple work arounds to kinda navigate?**
`Because I just need a simple snippet of code that understand`
`Under this App` or `System`
Do key press `Control+Left`

**What Language are you using for app?**
`Javascript`
`Node JS`